# Meaning of "could" in this context

Tags: meaning

"We can't give him the code, even though he has your wife. The deal is not worth it. The code could kill millions. We can not let that happen. We can not afford millions to die."

"The code could kill millions." Shouldn't "could" be "would" since it is saying that if the code is used, it would kill millions? Is "The code could kill millions" saying that if it is used, it is possible to kill millions (not guaranteed), or will kill millions if used?

Comment: *Could* does not mean the same thing as *would*; they have totally different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Both *would* and *could* are **modal auxiliary verbs.**

The following two quotes are from Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage:*

> We use *could* for **'general ability'** — for example to say that somebody could do something at any time, whenever he/she wanted.

and

> ...we use past tenses and *would* to **'distance' our language from reality.**

When using *could,* it implies that the situation is *plausible.*  On the other hand, *would* suggests that the situation is *hypothetical.*

The author is trying to show that the situation (in which the code kills millions of people) is *plausible,* so the characters have to stop it from happenning.